# How to remotely control Windows PC with Android?

Tags: applications, google-play-store, windows

Is there a way to remotely access my Windows PC with Android Phone and able to control it.

```
System Config: Windows 10, Model Lenovo

Android Config: Android 10, Poco X2
```

I want to access the PC by connecting different networks(I mean both are not connected to the same network)

Comment: A Windows Pro/Enterprise system can be controlled via RDP (have to be enabled on Windows). Besides that the standard screen-sharing systems like TeamViewer and so on are available as app for Android.

Comment: @Robert Could you please explain how windows can be controlled via RDP

Comment: @Robert I'm using Windows Enterprise

Comment: Just use Google for "RDP enable" and you are getting here: https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/turn-on-remote-desktop-in-windows-vista/ Note that you should not export TCP port 3389 to the Internet, otherwise hackers will try to break your username/password and take over your system.